# Why does WebView format (only) my Google search result page incorrectly?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface, webview

I am trying to develop a (very) simple web app that allows you to browse the web with large, easy to read text. When I turn the tablet to be in landscape mode, the Google search results do not expand to fit the whole screen, which defeats the purpose of creating an app with easy to read text.

For reference, I have attached images of my problem below along with my code. The Google page is presented in a narrow column, while other websites can be viewed as intended. What could be causing this, and can I solve this programmatically or do I need to find an alternative to Webview?

[Google results formatted incorrectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVe0B.jpg)

[Other website formatted correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqhRU.jpg)

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Web Browser',
      home: WebBrowser(),
    );
  }
}

class WebBrowser extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebBrowser({super.key});

  @override
  _WebBrowserState createState() => _WebBrowserState();
}

class _WebBrowserState extends State<WebBrowser> {
  late WebViewController _controller;
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controllerCompleter =
      Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
  }

  Future<bool> _canGoBack() async {
    bool canGoBack = await _controller.canGoBack();
    return canGoBack;
  }

  Future<bool> _canGoForward() async {
    bool canGoForward = await _controller.canGoForward();
    return canGoForward;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 120,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey,
            /*borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
            ),*/
          ),
          child: NavigationControls(
            webViewControllerFuture: _controllerCompleter.future,
            canGoBack: _canGoBack,
            canGoForward: _canGoForward,
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return WebView(
                initialUrl: 'https://www.google.com',
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                  _controllerCompleter.future
                      .then((value) => _controller = value);
                  _controllerCompleter.complete(webViewController);
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}

class NavigationControls extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<WebViewController> webViewControllerFuture;
  final Future<bool> Function() canGoBack;
  final Future<bool> Function() canGoForward;

  const NavigationControls(
      {super.key,
      required this.webViewControllerFuture,
      required this.canGoBack,
      required this.canGoForward});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
        future: webViewControllerFuture,
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> snapshot) {
          final bool webViewReady =
              snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done;
          final WebViewController? controller = snapshot.data;

          return Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                  size: 70,
                ),
                onPressed: !webViewReady || controller == null
                    ? null
                    : () async {
                        if (await canGoBack()) {
                          controller.goBack();
                        } else {
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            const SnackBar(
                              content: Text("No back history item"),
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                      },
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
              ),
              const Spacer(),
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                  size: 70,
                ),
                onPressed: !webViewReady || controller == null
                    ? null
                    : () async {
                        if (await canGoForward()) {
                          controller.goForward();
                        } else {
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            const SnackBar(
                              content: Text("No forward history item"),
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                      },
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 40.0),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}
```